# Custom columns are empty in my search content webpart, why?

Tags: search

I have added a search content webpart. I have changed the search query to get only results from contenttype X. This works. I have selected the display template "List". I have changed the mapped properties to show my custom columns. But they are empty. I have looked to these custom columns and they are available in the managed properties and crawl properties. I have did a full crawl. What do I missing?

Here you see the display template list and the property mappings. I  have selected 2 custom columns from the dropdown.

[image]

Here you see the results. The out of the box column (marked green) "Title" is working fine. The other 2 custom columns (marked red) has an empty value.

[image]

This is the contenttype with the Title and the 2 custom columns.

[image]

These are the managed properties. I didnt created them and I didnt edited them. They are created by SharePoint it self.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make it queryable and perform a full crawl

Comment: then, to be sure, do a search on your centre search site (usually https://mydomain.blablabla/search

Comment: I have backuped the contentdatabase and restore it in another environment/farm. Now it is working! So this problem is on a high level. Someone know where to look? Maybe the settings of the search service application?

Comment: I would check the permissions of the crawler on the Content. If it's a restored Content DB that may be the problem.